# In the Bible, have "good men" often set their hand against each other?

Tags: bible, ethics

(King) David, Samson, and Gideon, among others, were all robust slayers of enemies of Israel, most of whom were "bad" men.

In at least one instance, David set his hand against a good man, Uriah, for the wrong reason (he coveted Uriah's wife Bathsheba).

Was this an exception? Did the biblical heroes often go against an "innocent" good man like Uriah? Or did they go against (formerly) good men turned "bad" (e.g. David or Samuel against King Saul)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think part of the answer here is to deal with your concept of "Good Men". According to the Bible, all men are sinful, and so all men deserve death. No one is Good by himself, except God.

> **Luke 18:19 NIV** 
>   "Why do you call me good?" Jesus answered. "No one is good--except God alone.

Part of the purpose of the Bible is to show that we all need help, that none of us is good enough to make it on our own, and it's only because of the blood of Jesus that any of us has hope. For this reason the Bible shows flaws even in its heroes.

If you're looking for heroes in the Bible, the only person you need is Jesus Christ. He is the only man in the Bible that we can say is Good.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking on specific sin of killing an innocent person by an "Old Testament hero" (a patriarch, prophet, just king etc). This is quite rare in Bible. I haven't made a thorough search and I definitelly don't know all details of Old Testament by heart, but I don't remember any other case of this sin made by a just person.

But if you were asking about sins of just people in general, these were quite common. Abraham didn't wait for God's promise and had a son with Hagar, Moses beated to the rock twice, Aron made the golden calf...